# input field (width 100%) goes next line on simple 2 colum layout

Tags: html, css

I have a simple 2 colum layout (left col fixed width 200px, and right col expand 100%).

If the 1st element of the right col is a `P` element everything is OK.

But **when the 1st element of the right col is an `INPUT` element (`width:100%`), it goes down**.

The result displayed is below (tested on Chrome, FF, IE):

[image]

**Could you explain me why the INPUT field goes next line whilest the P element does NOT?** And how to fix this?

The code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
      body {background-color: #eeeeee;}
      div.left {float:left; width:200px; border:1px solid #ff0000;}
      div.right {     margin-left:200px; border:1px solid #00ff00;}            
      div.right p, div.right input {width:100%; border:1px dashed #0000ff;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   
   <div>
      <div class="left">
         <p>left div</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
         <p>I'm a P 100% width inside right div</p>
      </div>
   </div>

   <br>

   <div>
      <div class="left">
         <p>left div</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
         <input name="name" type="text" value="I'm an INPUT 100% width inside right div, why i'm down???">
      </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your CSS you are giving a `margin-left` to your right div tag without counting your borders' 1px of size.

I tried your example on my own with this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {background-color: #eeeeee;}
  div.left {float:left; width:200px; border:1px solid #ff0000;}
  div.right {margin-left:202px; border:1px solid #00ff00;}            
  div.right p {width:100%; border:1px dashed #0000ff;}
  div.right input {width:100%; border:1px dashed #0000ff;}
</style>
```

giving space to accommodate that offset.

Now It won't look like the first right div tag because `input` is dispalyed as inline instead of block, but you can make this change on the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why exactly it is handling it that way, but you can enclose your `<input>` in a `<p>` in order to correct the issue.

```
<div class="right">
         <p><input name="name" type="text" value="I'm an INPUT 100% width inside right div, why i'm down???" /></p>
</div>
```