# How do I make a text <input> tag as long as the div containing it?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a form input with a label next to it, like this:

```
<div id="loginbox">
    <form>
        <div>
            <span>Username</span>
            <input type="text">
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>Password</span>
            <input type="password">
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then I have some CSS that sets up the width of the login box and the span fields, like so:

```
#loginbox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}

#loginbox span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle for this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7TNNq/

Notice how the input boxes do not span the entire length of the div. How do I get it to expand fully?

Comment: Nope, you can try it for yourself in the jsFiddle. It sets the input width to the width of the entire div, not what's left after you set the span width.

Comment: What about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/scpike/6BXsh/1

Comment: True. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423485/css-input-field-width-100-goes-next-line-on-simple-2-cols-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/tgGLv/

**CSS:**

```
#loginbox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}

#loginbox label {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
#loginbox span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}
#loginbox span input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="loginbox">
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <span><input type="text"></span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <span><input type="password"></span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, wrapping it in the span tag works great. It's a shame we have to use workarounds like this to get it to work right though.

Answer (score 2):

You could put

```
#loginbox div input {
  width: 70%;  
}
```

it will expand to the edge of the div, but I'm sure there's a better way to go about it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/7TNNq/35/

Or you can set fixed width as @spike suggested.